# Open .vym files with View Your Mind

Tags: files

How can I open .vym files with View Your Mind? It is not listening in the open with dialog.

Answer (score 1):

View Your Mind accepts `.vym` files as command line arguments and is able to open them properly. But the problem resides in the default `.desktop` file shipped with the package.

You should edit `/usr/share/applications/vym.desktop`. To do so;

1. open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/vym.desktop
   ```
2. Find the line containing:

   ```
   Exec=vym
   ```
3. Add `%f` at the end of that line. It should look like:

   ```
   Exec=vym %f
   ```
4. Save and close the file.

Now Nautilus knows that View Your Mind is able to open files. Just right click on a `.vym` file, and go to "Open With" context menu. If you don't see View Your Mind in the list, click on "Other Application..." and "Show other applications" respectively and choose View Your Mind from the list.